# Why sed command doesn't work trying to extract scala version number

Tags: sed

I am trying to extract Scala major version using `sed` but it returns the same string back. I am not sure.

scala version:

```
scala -version
> Scala code runner version 2.13.7 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

Tried `sed` command is:

```
scala -version | sed 's/.*version \([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/'
> Scala code runner version 2.13.7 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

Screenshot:
[image]

But when I test my regex using [this website](https://sed.js.org/#) which is a sed playground it works.

Comment: You could try following command to get its version: `scala -version 2>&1 | sed 's/.*version \([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/'`. Check link https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/5866580 for understanding `2>&1` in detailed manner. I have also fixed your regex to get all 3 parts of version of scala.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it worked. Thank you. But why?

Comment: I have already updated my comment, kindly do check it once.

Comment: It doesn't look to me complete duplicate since I fixed your standard input/output along with your regex, for time being I have posted it in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your tried/attempted code. 1st: Is you need to send `scala --version` output to `2>&1`(check link https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/5866580 for understanding it better). 2nd: your regex is NOT catching exact version of scala, so you need to enhance it a bit, please try following `sed` command for same.

```
scala -version 2>&1 | sed 's/.*version \([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

***OR*** as an alternative you could use following `sed` command also:

```
scala -version 2>&1  | sed -E -n 's/.*version\s+([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+){2}.*/\1\2/p'
```